# spring mvc: accept non-urlencoded json payload

Tags: spring-mvc, urlencode

I'm looking at a request, sending some json to a spring mvc app (v4). The request is sent with a `Content-Type: application/json` header.

On the server side, the request handler is set with automatic serialization, through a `@RequestBody` annotation.

Everything's peachy right until I add a backslash to one of the variables in the payload. Then the server throws a 400 bad request.

I'd like to:

- keep the request payload as json
- not resort to manual encoding/decoding

How to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted.

Problem was on the client side: client code was writing-out a json string, instead of `JSON.stringify()`ing an object. Once that is fixed, `JSON.stringify()` presents the backslash correctly to the server (backslash is reserved in json for escaping).